# Why does Local Variables include other partitions when selecting?

Tags: database-partitioning, dolphindb

Currently, I have created the following partition:

```py
dbDate = database("", VALUE, 2010.01.01..2050.01.01)
dbSymbol = database("", HASH, [SYMBOL, 40])
db=database(db_name, COMPO, [dbDate, dbSymbol]);
```

When using the following code to query, I found that Local Variables will also load other date partitions

```py
db_name = "dfs://tick_database"
tb_name = "stock";
tb = loadTable(db_name, tb_name)
select * from tb where date(time)== 2021.08.24 and symbol == `000001.SZ
```

As the amount of data increases, Local Variables will soon reach the upper limit of 4g when selecting, how can I avoid this, or the database will automatically handle this situation, and there will be no Out or memory situation.

Answer (score 0):

After executing tb = loadTable(db_name, tb_name), the information of tb will be displayed, but this only displays the partition information. Only double-clicking it will load the specific partition data from the disk to the memory, so that users can query a partitioned table more conveniently. loadTable only loads metadata, which can be understood as a table object and occupies very little memory. Then after executing the SQL query on it, the data of the involved partition will be loaded into the memory. You can use getMemoryStat() to compare the memory used by the system before and after.